# Enumerate all unique simple arithmetic equations for a set of whole numbers

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, algorithms, arithmetic

When I was younger I used to play a game in my math class: The teacher had a deck of 3x5 cards with a digit written on each one. She would deal out several cards and state a target number, and our goal was to come up with an equation, using only those digits and the operators +,-,*,/ that equaled the stated target.

For example, if the digits were: 3,2,4,6 and the target was 10, you might come up with: `(6/2)+3+4 = 10`.

I was thinking about this game again recently, and wondered how many unique ways there are to generate a given target to see how "difficult" that target is.

I'm not sure if this is the best way to phrase what I'm asking, but I'm looking for a way to enumerate all the equations you can make with a set of digits and those basic operators (+,-,*,/) that are not redundant. For example, if using the digits 1,2,3, these two equations are redundant by the commutative property: `(1+2)+3` and `3+(1+2)`. In fact all equations using 1,2,3 and the addition operator (only) would be redundant: 1+2+3, 2+1+3, 3+1+2, etc.

Continuing the example from earlier (using the digits 3,2,4,6 and target 10), the equation `3+4+(6/2)` is redundant with the one shown earlier, but the alternative equation `(6/3)*4+2 = 10` is not. So there are at least 2 ways to make 10 out of those digits. I'm trying to figure out all the non-redundant ways to do so. Is that possible? Is there a better term to describe what I'm looking for?

Comment: With $n$ numbers there are $4^{n-1}n!$ expressions. $2(n!)$ are guaranteed redundant by your own logic. What else do you need to think about ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Can you explain how you determined those values? When asking the question I was hoping to learn whether there's a mathematical concept to describe what I'm calling "redundant", and whether there's some algorithm I could use to generate all non-redundant equations.

Comment: 4 operations, in $n-1$ spaces, and $n!$ ways to rearrange a distinct set of numbers.  2 fully commutative operations, and $n!$ ways to rearrange the numbers.

Comment: okay without parentheses placed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commutation can be captured by the following, moderately complicated, combinatorial object: a rooted tree whose root is labelled $+$ or $\times$, edges are labelled $+$ or $-$, and leaves are labelled with distinct variables. Every branch vertex must have at least two out-edges, and at least one must be labelled $+$.

The interior vertices can be implicitly labelled as the operation which their parent is not.

The value of a leaf is the value of its variable. The value of a $+$ vertex is the sum of its $+$-children minus the sum of its $-$-children. The value of a $\times$ vertex is the product of its $+$-children divided by the product of its $-$-children.

For example, the following tree represents $$\frac{a+b}{c}$$

[image: Tree with two internal nodes and children a,b,c]

Comment: Thanks! This pushes the limits of my math knowledge, but I think I follow. Would a generating function return the number of non-redundant functions (for each `n` number of input digits), or the functions themselves?
Is it possible to add an example of the rooted tree that you're describing? Perhaps for a simple case like digits 1,2,3 ?

Comment: @bantic, a generating function is (very informally) a function which expands as an polynomial whose coefficients count the object of interest. But on further reflection it would be counting trees without the variables filled in, which isn't very useful. If you want to produce the trees in code, I suggest ordering the $+$-children by the smallest variable in the subtree, and similarly the $-$-children.